# Hyperparameter optimization in BERT model

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-transformers, bert-language-model, huggingface

I am running the hugging face BERT model but cannot perform the hyperparameter optimization for training. I tried https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/hpo_train#hyperparameter-search-backend

but I have no clue about adding these functions in the training argument.

How can we optimise the BERT model?